# Can we combine two presets MongoDB and puppeteer in Jest?

Tags: mongodb, jestjs, puppeteer

Currently I am using Jest with puppeteer and I want combine that with MongoDB, is it possible to do that?

Here is my package.json look like:

```
{
  "name": "testing",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-puppeteer",
    "testMatch": [
      "**/tests/**/*.test.js"
    ],
    "testTimeout": 80000,
    "verbose": true
  }
}
```

and my jest-puppeteer.config.js looks like this

```
module.exports = {
  launch: {
    defaultViewport: {
      width: 1420,
      height: 1080,
    },
    devtools: false,
    headless: process.env.HEADLESS !== 'false',
    slowMo: process.env.SLOWMO ? process.env.SLOWMO : 0,
  },
};
```

Now I want to add mongoDB connection to the project with some predefined config something like this.

```
module.exports = {
  mongodbMemoryServerOptions: {
    binary: {
      version: '4.0.3',
      skipMD5: true
    },
    autoStart: false,
    instance: {}
  }
};
```

How do I combine puppeteer and mongoDB?

Comment: I don't see why not. Import mongo, import puppeteer and do your thing!

Comment: Then how about package.json what would be the preset then?

Comment: I'd add mongodb/mongoose to the dependencies. It wouldn't be any different than your normal mongo package.json--it's all Node, so you just add all the packages you want and have at it.